# How to create simple tcp_connect and tcp_write functions?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, connection

So I need2 functions: 1) `tcp_connect` that would try to connect to tcp adress (given string like `tcp://123.123.123.123:33333/`) capable of returning some bool if connection was sucsessfull and simple `tcp_write` function capable to write a buffer of given langth on to opened  connection. So where to get how to do it with boost? (please provide code, it  will be appreciated)

btw: how can we input into it normal url like tcp://www.bla-bla.com:port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::asio, and here is the code you need: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Comment: btw: can we input into it normal url like www.bla-bla.com ; port?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, you'd have to split the service from the address and pass the parts into the query to resolve for the end point.